# Resized image takes up too much UI space

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

I have an absolutely positioned round image. The image needs to take only 17% of screen width, and also be positioned 5 pixels from the top.

Problem is, when I resize the image to take up 17% of screen width, it does so but at the same time the container becomes elongated. The image itself does not stretch, but is positioned in the middle of the elongated Image container.

Styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    imageBase: {
        position: 'absolute',
        left: 15,
        top: 5,
        width: '17%',
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
});
```

What I'm rendering:

```
<Image 
       style = { styles.imageBase }
       source = { require('roundImage.png') }>
</Image>
```

Current result: [image: What it looks like now]

I need it to either cut off the extra space from the Image container, or position the image at the top of the container, instead of middle.

What I'm trying to do: 
[image]

Comment: did u tried to also add height with 17%?

Comment: Yes. That makes the image only a couple of pixels high :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is to wrap your image in a View with an [aspect ratio](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#aspectratio) of 1:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View
    style={{
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 15,
      top: 5,
      width: '17%',
      aspectRatio: 1,
    }}
  >
    <Image
      style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        resizeMode: 'contain',
      }}
      source={require('roundImage.png')}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```